# How to get day from specified date in android

Tags: android, date, dayofweek, weekday

Suppose my date is 02-01-2013

and it is stored in a variable like:

```
String strDate = "02-01-2013";
```

then how should I get the day of this date (i.e TUESDAY)?

Comment: still i am not doing any thing
i searched on net but not getting proper answer

Comment: am getting multiple date from remote server and am storing it into array of string

now for each date i want to find his day
so how should i do this in android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class from java api.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2008, 01, 01); // Note that Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.
int reslut = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch (result) {
case Calendar.MONDAY:
    System.out.println("It's Monday !");
    break;
}
```

You could also use [SimpleDateFormater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for parsing dates

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    date = date_format.parse("2008-01-01");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

calendar.setTime(date);
```

Comment: Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int val = calendar.get("05-01-2013");

suppose i use this then can he give me output as 
(SATURDAY)
?????

Comment: where should i pass my specified date in it

Comment: No, you could either set calendar's date by calendar.setTime(Date date) or just specify date while creating an instance of calendar class.

Answer (score 3):

First split the string

```
String[] out = strDate.split("-");
                    s1 = Integer.parseInt(out[0]);
                    s2 = Integer.parseInt(out[1]) - 1;
                    yr = out[2];
char a, b, c, d;
                    a = yr.charAt(0);
                    b = yr.charAt(1);
                    c = yr.charAt(2);
                    d = yr.charAt(3);
                    s3 = Character.getNumericValue(a)*1000 +
                         Character.getNumericValue(b)*100 +
                         Character.getNumericValue(c)*10 +
                         Character.getNumericValue(d);
```

then create a calendar instance on that day

```
Calendar cal        = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(s3, s2, s1);
```

then get the day

```
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: This will give required output, but why don't we use dateFormat.parse() to make it more simple?

Comment: Chinmoy Debnath
why u use
s2 = Integer.parseInt(out[1]) - 1;

-1 is here

Comment: In Calendar Class 0 means January, 11 means December. So i have decrement one from the month to reflect correct month.

Comment: that -1 saved my day

Answer (score 1):

use this format for date, day and time.

Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");

and get out put of object here with format method. 
ft.format(dNow)

Answer (score 0):

I think that based on Android documentation is suggested the use of Calendar,

You need to be careful because the first day 1 is [Sunday](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY) and the first month [January](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY)
Also check that you can get DAY_OF_WEEK, DAY_OF_MONTH etc