# Disable Sundays of every month in MaterialDateTimePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker). I want to disable particular weekday (like Sundays) of every month. Its mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599203/disable-specific-dates-of-day-in-android-date-picker) that we can do that using this library but `how to disable particular weekdays?` I can certainly limit the number of months using the short code available but I don't want to limit number of months just disable weekdays from selection.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private TextView dateTextView;
    private CheckBox modeDarkDate;
    private CheckBox vibrateDate;
    private CheckBox dismissDate;
    private CheckBox limitDates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find our View instances
        dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
        Button dateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date_button);


        modeDarkDate = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.mode_dark_date);
        vibrateDate = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.vibrate_date);
        dismissDate = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dismiss_date);
        limitDates = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.limit_dates);

        // check if picker mode is specified in Style.xml
        modeDarkDate.setChecked(Utils.isDarkTheme(this, modeDarkDate.isChecked()));


        // Show a datepicker when the dateButton is clicked
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                );
                dpd.setThemeDark(modeDarkDate.isChecked());
                dpd.vibrate(vibrateDate.isChecked());
                dpd.dismissOnPause(dismissDate.isChecked());


                if (limitDates.isChecked()) {
                 /*   Calendar[] dates = new Calendar[13];
                    for(int i = -6; i <= 6; i++) {
                        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                        date.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
                        dates[i+6] = date;
                    }  */

                // Add code here to disbale weekdays like Sundays.





                   // dpd.setSelectableDays(dates);
                }

                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = (DatePickerDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datepickerdialog");

        if(dpd != null) dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
        dateTextView.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118894/how-to-get-day-from-specified-date-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How to add this switch case in Calendar[] array?

Comment: If anyone knows how to disable Sundays or any other week days either using datepicker or custom calendarview, please comment.

Answer (score 15):

it is maybe a bit to late for this answer but I've got a solution that may help others. Please, try the following:

```
    // Calendar saturday;
    Calendar sunday;
    List<Calendar> weekends = new ArrayList<>();
    int weeks = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < (weeks * 7) ; i = i + 7) {
        sunday = Calendar.getInstance();
        sunday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SUNDAY - sunday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 + i));
        // saturday = Calendar.getInstance();
        // saturday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SATURDAY - saturday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
        // weekends.add(saturday);
        weekends.add(sunday);
    }
    Calendar[] disabledDays = weekends.toArray(new Calendar[weekends.size()]);
    dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
```

This code disables the next 5 Sundays, if you wish to do it for a longer period, just need to modify week. If you wish to disable Saturdays too, just uncomment those lines.

If you want to do it for previous 5 Sundays then, just modify the for loop to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (weeks * 7); i = i + 7) {
    for(int j =0; j > (weeks*7) ; j = j - 7);
    sunday = Calendar.getInstance();
    sunday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SUNDAY - sunday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 + i));
        // saturday = Calendar.getInstance();
        // saturday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SATURDAY - saturday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
        // weekends.add(saturday);
        weekends.add(sunday);
    }
```

so this second for loop will be used to disable previous 5 Sundays.

Comment: Hi,
from where we get setDisabledDays. Pls explain

Answer (score 1):

Based on Xavi Del Palacio answer I created more elastic method
In disabled days you add Calendar days like `disabledDays.add(Calendar.MONDAY)`

Sorry about using kotlin instead of java, just wanted to give an idea how to rework this method to be easier in use

```
private fun disableDatesFor4Weeks(disabledDays: ArrayList<Int>) {
        val disabledDaysInWeeks = ArrayList<Calendar>()
        disabledDays.forEach {
            dayInt ->
            var day: Calendar

            val weeks = 4

            var week = 0
            var i = 0

            while (week < weeks * 7) {
               day = Calendar.getInstance()
               day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayInt - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 * i)
               disabledDaysInWeeks.add(day)
               i += 1
               week += 7
           }
        }

        if (disabledDaysInWeeks.size > 0) {
            val disabledDaysInWeeksTypedArray = disabledDaysInWeeks.toTypedArray()
            datePickerDialog!!.maxDate = disabledDaysInWeeksTypedArray.last()
            datePickerDialog!!.disabledDays = disabledDaysInWeeksTypedArray
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> It might be late for answer i tried this code its disabled my sundays

```
            List<Calendar> dayslist= new LinkedList<Calendar>();
            Calendar[] daysArray;
            Calendar cAux = Calendar.getInstance();
            while ( cAux.getTimeInMillis() <= gc.getTimeInMillis()) {
                if (cAux.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 1) {
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTimeInMillis(cAux.getTimeInMillis());
                    dayslist.add(c);
                }
                cAux.setTimeInMillis(cAux.getTimeInMillis() + (24*60*60*1000));
            }
            daysArray = new Calendar[dayslist.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i<daysArray.length;i++)
            {
                daysArray[i]=dayslist.get(i);
            }
            datePickerDialog.setSelectableDays(daysArray);
```