# Java Calendar get() method is not working

Tags: java, android, calendar

I build an android calendar example, but I am weird when I worked with it.

I tried to get Monday this week which I set. However, within this code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int start = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

I cannot get right activity. A symptom is I can get right Monday of this week
but last week also gave me this monday, so I tried another code which is

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
int start = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
start = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Then I can get right activity what I want.

However I do not know why it is working and difference between these two codes.

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118894/how-to-get-day-from-specified-date-in-android

Comment: keep in mind that `Calendar.DATE` gives you the day of the month. If this was your intention, you better use `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`. Thats more concise.

Answer (score 0):

First importan info,calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient and non-lenient.


When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1.


When a Calendar is in non-lenient mode, it throws an exception if there is any inconsistency in its calendar fields. For example, a GregorianCalendar always produces DAY_OF_MONTH values between 1 and the length of the month. A non-lenient GregorianCalendar throws an exception upon calculating its time or calendar field values if any out-of-range field value has been set.


Another important info,calendar set method is only set the field value,but not update time and compute every fields(like year,month,day and so on) until you use any get method.

When Calendar run in lenient mode,here is code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setLenient(true);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

code run result is 10.
After call two set mothed, begin call get Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,now calendar begin to update time , Date 1 and DAY_OF_WEEK of MONDAY confuse , but Calendar is in lenient mode, final calculate the date 2016-10-10,so get result is 10.

same code in non-lenient mode:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setLenient(false);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DAY_OF_MONTH exception.

last code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
int start = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
start = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

code run result is 26.
when first call get Calendar.DATE,this call will updatetime and compute every fields . calculate date is 2016-10-01 .then call set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY), after this call get method,calculate date is 2016-09-26,so result is 26.